# Set the initial value for dynamic simulation w/ steady-state results in GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

I'm doing a dynamic simulation with 'IMODE=4'. I'm wondering if there is an option in the GEKKO to set the steady-state simulation result with 'IMODE=1' as an initial value of the dynamic simulation.

Or, do I need to run the steady-state simulation and set the values before running the dynamic simulation separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gekko automatically uses the values from a steady-state simulations of `IMODE` = 1 (SS) or 3 (RTO) to give initial values such as initial conditions for other modes. It is designed this way so that models can be initialized with a steady-state solution before starting dynamic modes such as simulation, moving horizon estimation, or model predictive control ([see IMODE summary](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Modes)).

[image: IMODE options]

Here is a minimal example script that demonstrates the initialization.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
p = m.Param(5)
x = m.Var(3)
m.Equation(p==x.dt()+x)

# steady-state (SS) simulation
m.options.IMODE=1
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value)

# dynamic simulation initialized with SS solution
m.time = [0,1,2,3,4]
p.value = 4
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value)
```

There is a default value of `x=3`. The steady state simulation solves with `p=5` to give `x=5` from the steady-state equation `5=0+x`. The dynamic simulation then solves the ODE with equation `4=dx/dt+x` to give a solution `[5.0, 4.5, 4.25, 4.125, 4.0625]` at the requested time points of `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Note that the initial condition is `5`, not `3`, because the dynamic simulation is initialized from the steady-state solution.